# Null statement execution time in C

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

How does the compiler interpret null statements in C? In terms of execution time. ( empty ";" i.e., without any expression)
And will it optimize code during execution if it encounters null statements,  by removing them.

Comment: Tip: Check the compiler assembly output and find out. Most compilers are a lot smarter than you'd think, especially with optimization turned on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compilers only care about observable behaviour. Whether you compile

```
int main() {
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   return 0;
}
```

or

```
int main() {
    ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    return 0;
}
```

does not make any difference regarding the resulting executable. The observable behaviour of both examples is the same.

If you want to convince yourself, look at the compilers output (this is a great tool: https://godbolt.org/z/bnbxiP) or try to profile the above examples (but dont expect to get meaningful numbers ;).

My suggestion is to not think about code as a way to talk to your cpu. When you write code you are not expressing instructions for your cpu. Code is rather a recipe for the compiler and your compiler knows much better how to intruct the cpu than any human. Small difference but I think it helps.

Comment: People often use comments like `/****************/` or `///////////////////////` to separate sections of their program.  It had never occurred to me that one might use `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;` as well.

Comment: @SteveSummit it actually is much better than ///// or similar comments, because the compiler ignores comments but will detect typos in code :p